# How to set javascript absolute link path in html file (all on local computer)?

Tags: javascript, html, linker

I'm having a problem creating an absolute path to a javascript file.

I have an html file E:\websites\usr\test_pages\mathjax\Number_equations\11e_number_equation.html.
This file needs to load javascript E:\websites\usr_scripts\mathjax\number_equations_11b.js.

In 11e_number_equation.html the following relative path works but is awkward --
`<script type="text/javascript" src="..\..\..\..\usr\_scripts\mathjax\number_equations_11b.js"></script>`

With the above I can ctrl+click on ........\usr_scripts\mathjax\number_equations_11b.js and the js file opens in a new tab.

The following absolute paths don't work --

`<script type="text/javascript" src="\websites\usr\_scripts\mathjax\number_equations_11b.js"></script>` ==> Gives message, "Unable to open file because the file was not found".

Adding the E: drive letter --
`<script type="text/javascript" src="E:\websites\usr\_scripts\mathjax\number_equations_11b.js"></script>` ==> This isn't recognized as a possible path (can't ctrl+click).

In the above situation, is there a way to enter an absolute path instead of a relative path?

VS Code 1.77.3
Windows 10 Pro

Thanks,
Don C.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the file URI scheme **file:///**

```
file:///E:/websites/usr........
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme